# Heroku container push fail: "no basic auth credentials ▸ Error: docker push exited with Error: 1"

Tags: heroku, docker

Once again, what worked perfectly three days ago fails today.

```
heroku container:login
Login Succeeded
```

.
.

```
 docker login
 .
 .
 Login Succeeded
```

.
.

```
heroku container:push web -a blah
=== Building web (/Users/.../Dockerfile)
Sending build context to Docker daemon  42.85MB
.
.
Successfully built 6c1f0a3c65c8
Successfully tagged registry.heroku.com/blah/web:latest
=== Pushing web (/Users/cw/../Dockerfile)
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/blah/web]
ccbc2f4c4f90: Preparing 
c002d03955d7: Preparing 
669a1b7e3876: Preparing 
99c1e51e4548: Preparing 
200d6216fb4b: Preparing 
887d646f7070: Waiting 
c167acc9a8e9: Preparing 
577d182336e4: Preparing 
2147747beb86: Preparing 
1591bf7ec708: Preparing 
dd3097cd7909: Waiting 
685934357c89: Waiting 
ccb9b68523fd: Waiting 
00bcea93703b: Waiting 
688e187d6c79: Waiting 
no basic auth credentials
 ▸    Error: docker push exited with Error: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just log in to the Heroku Docker registry before.

```
heroku auth:token | docker login --username=_ registry.heroku.com --password-stdin
```

Docs. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#logging-in-to-the-registry

Answer (score 1):

[this has been superseded by answer above.]

Now it pushes successfully, following (of course) the exact same steps.

Is this an answer? Perhaps. Perhaps whatever was wrong with  Heroku container last night was resolved by this am.

Answer (score 1):

After a month of coding it was time to push and had the same issue.  THIS time, I think this is actually a workable answer:

From Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#logging-in-to-the-registry):

```
$ docker login --username=_ --password=$(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com
```

(that's a direct quote.  you'd better ignore that underscore, though).

But where to get the [auth:token](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication)? Apparently you just need to login to Heroku:

```
Running heroku login (or any other heroku command that requires authentication) creates or updates your ~/.netrc file...
```

...and the `~/.netrc` file contains your `auth:token`.

Retrieve the auth:token

```
$ heroku auth:token
ff6-blah-blah-blah-2b
```

SO:

```
$ docker login --username=blah --password=$(ff6-blah-blah-blah-2b) registry.heroku.com
```

But then:

```
bash: ff6-blah-blah-blah-2b: command not found
```

so perhaps there's a bug? But not to worry, you get a second chance:

```
Password: ff6-blah-blah-blah-2b
```

That's right, your auth:token, NOT your password, despite what it says, and...

```
Login Succeeded
```

Which brought happiness in this form:

```
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/blah/web]
880ed5cb8cce: Preparing 
d65226c5343a: Pushed 
88f6abcdc67e: Pushed 
b4d4668b5618: Pushed 
5d7ae135e193: Pushed 
a844ed4bf9ae: Pushed 
3b70de5cb989: Pushed 
c023cf8fe796: Pushed 
b5694bda03f5: Pushed 
4b4c002ee6ca: Pushed 
cdc9dae211b4: Pushed 
7095af798ace: Pushed 
fe6a4fdbedc0: Pushed 
e4d0e810d54a: Pushed 
4e006334a6fd: Pushed 
latest: digest: sha256:e1 - - - d1 size: 3479
```

Comment: The best answer I have ever seen on stack overflow!